# Unexpected: Wordpress redirects to the WP_HOME/WP_SITEURL value

Tags: redirect, wp-config

Hello Wordpress colleagues,

I'm working on existing WP instance (5.2.5) having an issue with WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME defined in wp-config.php.

Expected Result: I expect WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME to control links but not cause 301 Redirect.

**Actual Result: WP issues a 301 redirect if WP instance is loaded on URL that does not match WP_SITEURL or WP_HOME.**

What I have done to debug the problem:

1. Installed new instance of 5.2.5 with new database. Set WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL to https://example.com. Loaded the WP Instance and observed no 301 Redirect.
2. Pointed new instance of 5.2.5 to the existing database -> 301 Redirect.
3. Renamed plugins and themes folders in wp-content in existing instance -> 301 Redirect persists.

Comment: Why don't you expect a redirect?

Comment: @JacobPeattie I do not expect a redirect because the new installation of 5.2.5 does not issue a redirect like the existing instance does. Also, this WP instance will be behind the Load Balancer so with the redirect it would be impossible to make it work behind the LB. Thank you for your question.